# Replace the numeric ID in the string to a string with accent mark

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have a text with values as \xe1, \xed, etc. and I want the text with accent mark i.d. á, í.

```
test = 'Bicicleta en Bogot\\xe1'
test1 = test.encode('utf-8')

print test1
Bicicleta en Bogot\xe1
```

output
Bicicleta en Bogot\xe1

I want output:
Bicicleta en Bogotá

Comment: Is this python2? That matters for text related stuff. Please add a tag for it.

Comment: Add a `u` before the string

Comment: You have actually the four characters \, x, e and 1 in your string, not the single character `E1` inserted by an escape sequence. Cf. `len('Bogot\\xe1')` vs. `len('Bogot\xe1')`.

Comment: If your input actually looks like what you showed, then the linked answer doesn't help you. Instead, you should try `test.decode('unicode_escape')`.